# JavaScript functions and objects variable assigning

Tags: javascript

```
function addOne(){
  // Anything
}

addOne // Output:f addOne(){...}

addOne.count = 0;

console.log(addOne.count, addOne); // Output: 0 and f addOne() {...}
```

So how come `addOne` is function as well as acts as an object?

Comment: "*So how come addOne is function as well as acts as an object ?*" the obvious answer is...that functions are objects. The only special thing is that they are callable but are otherwise still just an object.

Comment: Every function in JavaScript is a Function object.

Answer (score 0):

That's because every function in JavaScript is an object. Take a look at this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: Agreed!, But How do you access these keys and values of an object ?